# (Python) Concatenate dataframes with different, mismatching indices

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, concatenation

I'd like to concatenate two dataframes with different indices, but only keep the lines in which both dataframes have data in it.

df1=

```
Index    coords    Time_end    duration    value
0        5             10          5           1.0
1        -10            16          6          3.2
...
39       50            53          3           5.4
```

df2=

```
Index    pvt_rate    
3        5.3        
4        12.0      
...
39       34.2
...
63       8.6
```

I'd like to get something like this:
df3=

```
Index    coords    Time_end    duration    value    pvt_rate
3        5             10          5           1.0      5.3
4        -10            16          6          3.2      12.0
...
39       50            53          3           5.4      34.2
```

I've tried this:
`df3=pd.concat([df1,df2],axis=1,join="inner")`

But it returns an error:
`pandas.errors.InvalidIndexError: Reindexing only valid with uniquely valued Index objects`

Comment: `df1.merge(df2, on='Index')` (assuming Index is a column), else `df1.join(df2)`